# Why do maps in Go initially have empty values depending on size of the map?

Tags: go

Hoping to understand maps in Go better.

Given this code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    Lat, Long float64
}

var m []map[string]Vertex
var m1 map[string]Vertex

func main() {
    m = make([]map[string]Vertex, 3)
    m1 = make(map[string]Vertex)
    m1["Bell Labs"] = Vertex{
        40.68433, -74.39967,
    }
    m = append(m, m1)
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println(len(m))
    fmt.Println(m[3]["Bell Labs"])
}
```

I get an output of

```
[map[] map[] map[] map[Bell Labs:{40.68433 -74.39967}]]
4
{40.68433 -74.39967}
```

Why is it that the first 3 elements in the array are empty/null maps, shouldn't it print out `[map[Bell Labs:{40.68433 -74.39967}]]` instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why is it that the first 3 elements in the array are empty/null maps?

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Making slices, maps and channels](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Making_slices_maps_and_channels)
>
> The built-in function make takes a type T, which must be a slice, map
>   or channel type, optionally followed by a type-specific list of
>   expressions. It returns a value of type T (not *T). The memory is
>   initialized as described in the section on initial values.
>
> ```
> Call             Type T     Result
>
> make(T, n)       slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity n
> make(T, n, m)    slice      slice of type T with length n and capacity m
> ```

---

The slice `m` of `map`

```
m = make([]map[string]Vertex, 3)
```

is equivalent to

```
m = make([]map[string]Vertex, 3, 3)
```

it should be

```
m = make([]map[string]Vertex, 0, 3)
```

---

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Vertex struct {
    Lat, Long float64
}

var m []map[string]Vertex
var m1 map[string]Vertex

func main() {
    m = make([]map[string]Vertex, 0, 3)
    fmt.Println(len(m), cap(m))
    m1 = make(map[string]Vertex)
    m1["Bell Labs"] = Vertex{
        40.68433, -74.39967,
    }
    m = append(m, m1)
    fmt.Println(m)
    fmt.Println(len(m), cap(m))
    fmt.Println(m[0]["Bell Labs"])
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/i9f0rrCrtY_5

Output:

```
0 3
[map[Bell Labs:{40.68433 -74.39967}]]
1 3
{40.68433 -74.39967}
```